# Is it possible to sync a Photos library hosted on external HD with iCloud?

Tags: icloud, photos

I have a ~90 GB Photos library on an external hard drive. Every time I want to access those photos, I need to have access to and to connect this hard drive. I was thinking about syncing with iCloud so:

1. I can access a copy of the photos wherever I have an Internet connection.
2. I would also have an offsite backup.

My question: Is it merely a matter of going into System Preferences → iCloud → and ticking the Photos box? If it is, I’m guessing I must have the external hard drive (where the Photos library it) connected when I do it, and must be ready to leave it connected for a while (maybe overnight) while it syncs with iCloud?

Comment: Do you have enough storage on your iCloud to accommodate ~90 GB pictures?

Comment: Yes of course: I’ve sign up for the 200 GB plan.

Comment: And thanks for the edits: I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it merely a matter of going into System Preferences → iCloud → and ticking the Photos box?

Yes.

> If it is, I’m guessing I must have the external hard drive (where the Photos library it) connected when I do it, and must be ready to leave it connected for a while (maybe overnight) while it syncs with iCloud?

Yes,

Comment: Thank you: I will execute and report back with the results.

Comment: There are a couples of things to consider. When opening an external photo library (stored on an external hard drive) on a Mac, using Photos, one must tell Photos to use this external photo library “as System Photo Library” in order for iCloud to start backing it up. This is done in Photos > Preference > General.

Comment: When that is done, in Photos > Preferences > iCloud it becomes possible to check “iCloud Photos”. Underneath this, there are two options: “Download Originals to this Mac” which I believe should be left UNCHECKED especially if the goal is to save storage on the Mac itself. And then “Optimize Mac Storage” I’m not sure what that option will achieve nor if it will take space (and if so how much) on the Mac itself.